# overlay and center images

Tags: html, css, centering

I have two images, of unknown but equal size, which I would like to be horizontally centered, on top of each other, and vertically within the flow of my page. I have tried:

```
<div>text before the image</div>
<div style="text-align: center"><img src="A.png" /></div>
<div style="text-align: center"><img src="B.png" /></div>
<div>text after the image</div>
```

This centers the images, but does not overlay them on top of each other. I have tried:

```
<div>text before the image</div>
<div style="text-align: center">
    <div style="position: absolute"><img src="A.png" /></div>
    <div style="position: absolute"><img src="B.png" /></div>
</div>
<div>text after the image</div>
```

This overlays the two images, but does not center them (which I hoped "text-align: center" would help with), and interacts badly with the text after the image (which I had hoped the wrapper `div` would help with).

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something css like:

```
img.overlay {
margin:auto;
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;}
```

reference: http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt

I believe you can go with position:fixed as well :)

EDIT: like this:

```
<div>text before the image</div>
<div style="position:relative;">
    <img src="A.png" style="visibility:hidden;" /> <!-- spacer -->
    <img src="A.png" class="overlay" />
    <img src="B.png" class="overlay" />
</div>
<div>text after the image</div>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this does not meet the "within the flow of my page" requirement: the image does not necessarily appear between "text before the image" and "text after the image".

Comment: Well, you can set the div that holds both the images to be width:100%; height:30%; Does that work for you?

Comment: Changing the width and height of the containing `div` does not seem to affect the positioning of the contained images at all. Using your edit, the contained image is still in the wrong place, and there's a big empty space in between "text before the image" and "text after the image".

Comment: I believe we have a miscommunication about what "centered" means. I've edited my question to be more clear; the relevant clarification is that I'd like the images to be _horizontally_ centered, but vertically I would like them to be a part of the page (i.e. between "text before the image" and "text after the image").

Comment: ok, there I updated, added position:relative; to the outer div.

Comment: Aha, great. This requires me to know the height of the image, which is unfortunate... but fits all my other criteria well.

Comment: Your welcome :) ... You can set img{height:100%;} and set the outer div to specific height.. I would add max-height:100%;and max-width:100%; to the img as well... Oh well, play around with it :P

Comment: you can mark this answer as correct to follow stack overflow's standards

Comment: Okay, I found a way to fulfill my final requirement (not knowing the image size): one can place an additional `<img style="visibility: hidden" src="A.png" />` inside the `div`. Since that rounds out the demands of the question, I'll edit your answer shortly and mark it accepted. Thanks for the tips!